# Joining multiple sources using mapping dataflows

Tags: sql, azure-data-factory

I have seen many examples of joining 2 sources in mapping dataflows but cannot grasp the concept clearly, and maybe join is not an answer to my problem after all.

I have few csv files in blob storage.

All different names and different columns.
for example:

1. Customer
2. Site
3. service
4. Vendor

from data perspective all tables have some sort of connection to another. You could easily join these tables together in sql using Pk and FK's.

What I want is, to get all these tables into one output file.

I am not sure if I should be using Join in ADF data flow, or UNION or merge in copy activity??

can someone help please!

Thanks

Comment: From a brief look that a JOIN would make sense since you mentioned they have some connection to join each other, but it would be helpful if you can give us some sample dataset and the expected output to see how we can help.

Comment: @gumdrop  If my answer was helpful , You can Accept it as an Answer, so that others who encounter the same issue can find this solution and fix their problem.

Answer (score 0):

In ADF, you will build Joins visually inside the Data Flow component. Add a Data Flow activity to your pipeline canvas and inside of the data flow designer, add your source and a Join transformation. That is where you can set the relationships and join types.

Answer (score 0):

You can join two sources in Azure Data Factory.

Create Data Flow Activity in Azure Data Factory.

[image]

In Data Flow, add Sources from blob storage and Select Join as shown in below image.

[image]

In Join activity, you can Select join type, also you can add Condition to join multiple sources. Refer below image.

[image]

Finally add Sink file and Run Pipeline.